# Remote Powershell Sessions randomly die

Tags: windows-10, powershell

The Powershell code below is how I am starting the remote `PSSession`.

```sh
$compName = "server1"

$jobname = "admin_test"

$cred = Get-Credential -UserName "DOMAIN\$env:username" -Message "DOMAIN\$env:username password"

$s_opt = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout -1

$s1 = New-PSSession -ComputerName $compName -Name $jobname -SessionOption $s_opt -Credential $cred
```

This works great for the most part and we are able to `$s1 | Enter-PSSession` and run commands, or use `Invoke-Command -Session $s1 -ScriptBlock {some code}`.  When we run particular jobs (usually python or java) that may take many hours to complete, sometimes the PSSession dies unexpectedly.

Do I need to add different or more `-SessionOption`s ?

Is there a way to find out why the PSSession died ?

### Edit

Below is the output of `New-PSSessionOption`

```sh
PS C:\> New-PSSessionOption

MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount : 5
NoCompression                     : False
NoMachineProfile                  : False
ProxyAccessType                   : None
ProxyAuthentication               : Negotiate
ProxyCredential                   :
SkipCACheck                       : False
SkipCNCheck                       : False
SkipRevocationCheck               : False
OperationTimeout                  : 00:03:00
NoEncryption                      : False
UseUTF16                          : False
IncludePortInSPN                  : False
OutputBufferingMode               : None
MaxConnectionRetryCount           : 0
Culture                           :
UICulture                         :
MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommand :
MaximumReceivedObjectSize         :
ApplicationArguments              :
OpenTimeout                       : 00:03:00
CancelTimeout                     : 00:01:00
IdleTimeout                       : -00:00:00.0010000
```

### Edit 2

I added code below to my routine to start the `PSSession`, however the `PSSession` still stops for no reason after about 2 hours.

```sh
## -IdleTimeoutSec in sec/min * min/hr * hrs/day * days
Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s1 -IdleTimeoutSec 60*60*24*3
```

This was based on the following the description of `-IdleTimeoutSec` optional parameter in Microsoft's Powershell docs [Disconnect-PSSession](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/disconnect-pssession?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters)

Also explained well in the ninth command of Example 3 of the MS docs for the Powershell command `Connect-PSSession` [Examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/connect-pssession?view=powershell-6#examples) excerpted below.

```sh
# The ninth command disconnects from the session in the $s variable.The administrator closes PowerShell and closes the computer. She can reconnect to the session on the next day and check the script status from her work computer.
PS C:\> Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s -OutputBufferingMode Drop -IdleTimeoutSec 60*60*15
```

One crazy thing that is either an error in the MS docs or has to do with a different Powershell version is that the command above gives the following error:

```sh
Disconnect-PSSession : Cannot bind parameter 'IdleTimeoutSec'. Cannot convert value "60*60*24*3" to
type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:76
+ ... sion -Session $x -IdleTimeoutSec 60*60*24*3
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Disconnect-PSSession], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Disconnect
   PSSessionCommand
```

However, the following command works fine when the integer value passed to `-IdleTimeoutSec` is converted to a string.

```sh
PS C:> Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s1 -IdleTimeoutSec "259200"

 Id Name            ComputerName    ComputerType    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  5 admin_test      Server1         RemoteMachine   Disconnected  Microsoft.PowerShell          None
```

Comment: Concerning the "Input string was not in a correct format." error: You need to wrap the calculation in parentheses: `-IdleTimeoutSec (60*60*24*3)`

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into another default timeout parameter than `IdleTimeout`
that you have used.

Run the command `New-PSSessionOption` without parameters (include the output
in your post if you wish us to have a look).
Pay special attention to `OperationTimeout`.

From the documentation for 
[New-PSSessionOption](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption?view=powershell-6):

> **-OperationTimeout**
>
> Determines the maximum time that any operation in the session can run.
>   When the interval expires, the operation fails. Enter a value in
>   milliseconds.
>
> The default value is 180000 (3 minutes). A value of 0 (zero) means no
>   time-out; the operation continues indefinitely.

Comment: edited OP to include output of `New-PSSessionOption`

Comment: Also added other things I have tried like `Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s1 -IdleTimeoutSec 60*60*24*3`  - Session still stops after ~ 2 hours.

Comment: Your OperationTimeout is still 3 minutes. I think that the documentation of Powershell is not fully correct, but it's still a mystery that your operation works successfully for 2 hours.

Comment: the final code `Disconnect-PSSession -Session $s1 -IdleTimeoutSec "259200"` seems to be working.  I have had a simple job running successfully in that PSSession for approximately 20 hours now.

Comment: Seems that OperationTimeout is ignored, but one never knows, and the next major update to Windows 10 arrives very soon ... Wouldn't hurt to set it also to "259200".